# fread() - Want to read an integer but it is returning garbage

Tags: c, file, fwrite, fread

I have a dynamic .txt file called **library.txt**, which has only one line of data. It is exactly this one:

```
63Book Title1|Book Author 1|Book Editor 1|2014|English|255|99.989998|
```

I'm trying to read the first integer on the file (in this case, the number "63") using the **void readInteger()** function that I created:

```
void readInteger(){
FILE *arq = fopen("library.txt", "r+");
if(arq == NULL){
    printf("ERROR WHILE OPENING FILE!!!");
    return;
}

int x;
fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, arq);
printf("%d", x);
return;
}
```

But the function always keep printing the crazy number "1866609462".
Does anyone know what is wrong with my code? Can you guys help me please?

Comment: The file is stored as ascii characters. Not integers. That is, it is a text file not a binary file. Consider using `fscanf` instead for your intended purpose. Or `fgets` followed by manual parsing of each line (`strtok` is helpful in that case).

Comment: `fread` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fread` is not the right function to use to read formatted data. Use `fscanf` instead.

```
fscanf(arq, "%d", &x);
```